# Repetition Structures, Procedure Method

Tags: java, bluej

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
        String c = "Message";
        int width;
        int height;
        char character;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the character : ");
        character = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter your width: ");
        width=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your height: ");
        height=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == height-1) {
                    System.out.print(character);
                } else if (j ==width-1) {
                    String middle = character + "  " + c + "  " + character;
                    System.out.print(middle);
                } 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

}

I am trying to make the MESSAGE display in the rectangle. Also, is there a way i can move my rectangle in the center of the screen too?

Comment: Rustam, can u please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will do your trick but please notice that this is ugly.
First you are taking the whole user input line instead of the first character.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String c = "Message";
    char character;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the character : ");
    character = sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2) {
                System.out.print(character);
            } else if (j == 0) {
                String middle = character + "  " + c + "  " + character;
                System.out.print(middle);
            } 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
a  Message  a
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: what do u mean by it's ugly?

Comment: You may want to explain what's going on to the OP in addition to giving the code...

Comment: also, is there a way i can make the rectangle(with message) move in the middle of the screen

Comment: what if it will be more than 13. will it print as such.?

Comment: that is why I said "ugly", try everytime to avoid to hardcode your variable

Comment: is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: of course you can. Take the width of the rectangle, minus 2 (for the left and right character), then remove also the length of the message. Now you it remains only the free space which you will have to divide by 2. String middle = character + freeSpace/2 + message + freeSpace/2 + character;

Comment: @capslock, if u don't mind can u check my new code? and edit that please

Comment: Take a look at this, and try fo finish it by yourself http://pastebin.com/DAN1QsdY

Comment: @capslock, i tested it and it shows the string c"message" two times, in the box, when i only want it once. Is there a way, i can do it with the code i edited above, rather than using the link u gave me

Comment: @caps lock please help me

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the [for loop], the StringUtils class in [Apache Commons Lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) can help you make repeating String.

See:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

there are 3 methods:

(1)static String repeat(char ch, int repeat)

Returns padding using the specified delimiter repeated to a given length.

(2)static String repeat(String str, int repeat)

Repeat a String repeat times to form a new String.

(3)static String repeat(String str, String separator, int repeat)

Repeat a String repeat times to form a new String, with a String separator injected each time.